# SQL Server on Azure has slowed to half speed

Tags: sql-server, azure

We recently ran out space on a Azure database. After deleting a lot of unused tables, (none of which had indexes, or even keys,) Transact queries take almost exactly twice as long. SSIS imports seem to be completely unaffected.

After the obvious step of shrinking the log file, I'm now totally baffled.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've done lots of deleting and shrinking, then you probably need to reindex your database now.

Comment: Yep your indexes could get fragmented after a lot of bulk operations, you might need to reIndex them

Comment: [here](https://thinkrethink.net/2018/07/09/run-maintenance-jobs-on-azure-sql/) is a nice article about detecting fragmentation and automating the azure sql maintenance

Comment: As I said no indexes on any of the deleted tables and those tables that do have indexes are all well under 10%

Answer (score 0):

After you deleted a lot of unused tables, the database space will not be released automatically in SQL Server.

For a test, you can migrate you data to another database and run the same query, comparing the query time it costs.

Since you have tried to shrink the log file, I suggest you can also try the database shrinking. 
Login you SQL Database with SSMS:

right-click `your database`---->`Tasks` ---->`Shrink`---->`Database`:
[image]
Another way is setting database `Auto Shrink`:

right-click `your database`---->`Properties`, set `Auto Shrink`---->`True`:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @leon-yue but neither of these options are available. I presume you're looking at a stand alone SQL Server rather than Azure.